# Loading a register from a "db 0" doesn't load a 0 into EAX?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I've been bashing my head against the wall for over an hour and I can't understand why the below doesn't work.
If I change `b: db 1` to `b: db 0` then it should print 10, otherwise it should print 0.  Instead, the program always prints 10.

I've been writing a project that writes assembly and this is one of the unit test that fails and I just don't get it.  It has to be something simple.

```
extern printf, exit

section .bss

section .data
b: db 1
x: dd 5
y: dd 5
z: dd 0
int_pattern: db "%i", 10, 0

global main

section .text

main:
mov eax, dword [b]
cmp eax, dword 0
je condition_end4

; add x and y
; store into z
mov eax, dword [rel x]
add eax, dword [rel y]
mov [rel z], eax

condition_end4:

; rsi = &z
; rdi = &int_pattern
mov rsi, qword [z]
mov rdi, int_pattern
; not using vector registers
xor rax, rax
; printf(int_pattern, z);
call printf
```

I'm using Debian Linux with NASM. Assembling/linking with

```
nasm -f elf64 -o test.o test.asm
gcc test.o -o test.bin
```

Even when `b` is 0, GDB shows that the `cmp` unsets ZF so I'm at a loss here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've declared b as a byte:

```
b: db 1
```

but you load it as a dword:

```
mov eax, dword [b]
```

This explains why the zero flag is unset even when b is 0: because it's loading the next 3 bytes as well.

Just change your declaration:

```
b: dd 1
```

Alternatively, you could load a byte with zero extension: `movzx eax, byte [b]`

---

Similarly, you load a qword from `z` but you only defined it as a `dd` dword.  See [Which variable size to use (db, dw, dd) with x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168743/which-variable-size-to-use-db-dw-dd-with-x86-assembly)

Also, use `default rel` so all addressing modes pick RIP-relative addressing without having to say `[rel b]` everywhere.