# Why can db accept more than 1 byte?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

If `db` stands for **Define Byte** and can hold 8 bits (1 byte), why can we use a 6 bytes string with `db`? I know that one character is only 1 byte, and `db` holds 1 byte.

```
section .data
    text db "Yellow"
```

`db` is playing like a `char` in more high level languages (compared to asm), which we can just increase the buffer, but assembly does it automatically?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c = 'Y';
    char string[7] = "Yellow";
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: define byte**s**

Comment: You might be getting a compiler warning for `char c = "Y";` which should be `char c = 'Y';`

Comment: @ikegami I also thought like this, but look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168743/which-variable-size-to-use-db-dw-dd-with-x86-assembly)

Comment: `db` defines the size of each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data definitions `db`, `dw`, `dd`, `dq` etc. accept more than one value, they are stored successively. For example

```
db 'Y', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 0
```

is assembled as

```
59 65 6C 6C 6F 77 00
```

Since it is cumbersome to specify all characters individually, there is the notation as a string, both are equivalent:

```
db "Yellow", 0
```

Please note that the terminating zero byte must be specified separately in assembly (in contrast to C).

Comment: It's even the same in C (except that C adds a NUL). `char s[] = "Yellow";` is short for `char s[] = { 'Y', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 0 };`

Comment: Cool! I didn't know. @ikegami