# assembly code unexpectedly printing .shstrtab.text.data

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, ld

i am very new to assembly although i have lots of c and c++ experience.
my assembly code is supposed to print hello world like all first programs in a new language.
it prints out hello world but also prints out some extra text:

```
hello world!
.shstrtab.text.data
```

and here is my assembly program:

```
section .text
    global _start       ;for the linker
    
_start:
    mov edx, length     ; message length
    mov ecx, message    ; message to write
    mov ebx, 1      ; file descriptor stdout
    mov eax, 4      ; system call number
    int 0x80    ; call kernel
    
    mov eax, 1  ;system call number for sys_exit to exit program
    int 0x80    ; call kernel
    
section .data
message db "hello world!"
length DD 10
```

if you know how to fix this also explain why is this happening.
thanks.

extra info: i am using nasm assembler with ld linker

Comment: You want `mov edx,[length]` to load the value. You are loading the address which is likely a big number so you are printing extra stuff. You could also do `length equ 10` or similar, then you don't need the brackets. PS: run your code through `strace`.

Answer (score 1):

```
length equ $ - message
```

instead of `length dd 10`

Comment: Please put code in code-formatting, not a signature or whatever that is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is in adding length as it gives the address of length variable but not the value. the answer is to use `move edx, [length]`. thanks to Jester for pointing me that out

Comment: I would suggest this isn't the best way. I would go with Jester's other recommendation of changing `length dd 10` (which stores 10 in memory) to `length equ 10` which sets `length` to the constant 10 in the assembler. Then your `mov edx, length` can remain as is. I'd actually go one further and have the assembler compute the string length `length equ $-message` . That should work when placed directly after you string.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Indeed, to the point of having the assembler compute it, OP has actually computed it by hand and incorrectly, so the program will only output `hello worl`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the correct code and explain it. However, I'm not experienced enough to tell you, why your code doesn't work.

Here's the correct code :

```
section .text
    global _start       ;for the linker
    
_start:
    mov edx, length     ; message length
    mov ecx, message    ; message to write
    mov ebx, 1      ; file descriptor stdout
    mov eax, 4      ; system call number
    int 0x80    ; call kernel
    
    mov eax, 1  ;system call number for sys_exit to exit program
    int 0x80    ; call kernel
    
section .data
message db "hello world!"
length equ $-message
```

In `message db "hello world!"` - `message` is a label that stores the starting address of string "hello world!".

`db` means `define byte` which is used to allocate 1 byte of space for the label `message`.

**TWO VERY CRUCIAL THINGS TO REMEMBER:**

1. **Instructions are fetched, decoded and executed 1 AFTER ANOTHER**.
2. **Data and Instructions are stored in the same memory**.

This means each letter of "hello world" is written into the memory addresses **1 AFTER ANOTHER**.

You will end up at the **end of the string** after writing all the letters **1 by 1**.

Then you'll go to the **next memory address** which holds the next instruction `length equ $-message`.

In `length equ $-message` - The `$` represents the current address. So, you are subtracting the **start of string** (`message`) from **end of string** (`$`).

This gives you the length of the string without even having to calculate or write it manually.

There's one mistake I found in your code, you wrote `length DD 10`. Now the `length` is supposed to hold the length of the `message`.

However the length of message `hello world!` is 12 not 10. Another thing is `dd` means `define double word` which is generally 4 bytes and way much more memory space than required to store the length. [Here's a guide you can refer to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168743/which-variable-size-to-use-db-dw-dd-with-x86-assembly)

I hope this helps, have a good day.

Comment: Their code uses a huge size for `write` because their `length` is an address (`length: dd 10`).  So on the terminal they get all printable characters until the end of the page.  Use `strace ./hello` to see the system call it makes.